# parametros para funcao : referencia const e ponteiro para dados constante

Tags: c++

qual a diferença em termos de desempenho ( no caso de objeto grande) as chamadas abaixo:

```
void funcao( const tipo  &objeto )
```

e

```
void funcao( const tipo *objeto )
```

sei que na primeira recebe um referência constante, o que é bom para não precisar copiar o objeto , só cria um apelido para o objeto, e como e `const`, o objeto não pode ser modificado;

e (sei que) na segunda recebe o endereço do objeto , e como é `const`, o objeto não pode ser modificado.

Comment: Boa pergunta. Eu acredito que se tiver diferença de desempenho ela vai ser bem pequena, pois provavelmente o compilador se vira nessa diferenciação. P.S.: Vai ser uma daquelas perguntas que só o @bigown resolve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em princípio não faz nenhuma diferença, já que a implementação óbvia de um parâmetro por referência é simplesmente um ponteiro.